# cake php validation in one action visible in another

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have controller `users`.
In this controller I have action account which is doesn't do anything - it just has a view with multiple forms - change password, change something, block account etc. Each of this form links to some action: `users/changepassword`, `users/changesomething` etc.
These actions don't have any views, just some logic and validation during `save(..)` and at the end simple `redirect->( array( 'action' => 'account' ) );`. So to sum up - in users/account view there are several forms pointing to separate actions. These actions after logic execution redirect back to users/account.

Now The problem is that I want to see all invalid fields in any form that was submitted (according to validation rules) - this works if view is in the same action as controller but when I use redirect all invalid fields are lost - how I can workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1) Save the errors in the session, redirect back to accounts and set them there again.

2) And the better solution: Post all the forms to your account action and have a hidden field in each form containing the type or something. Based on the type call a model method that should do all the validation and save work if you followed MVC properly.